# Is it possible to create a Document Level Excel Customization with Office Addins?

Tags: excel, office-js

VBA and VSTO can create workbook level customizations. Is it possible to reach the same with Office Addins?

Suppose a scenario like this:
In the same company, a person use 2 Excel applications, each with its specific ribbons. When I use application A, I don't want to see ribbons from B and vice-versa.

Is this a predicated scenario using Office Addins or the idea is that it is only suitable for application level customization?

---

Edit for clarification:
In a company, I work with 2 main workbooks: Sales.xlsx and HumanResources.xlsx.
When I open the workbook Sales.xlsx, I want to see the ribbon groups that belong to actions that manipulate Sales data, visualization, specific commands, etc.
When I open the workbook HumanResources.xlsx, I want to see the equivalent for Human Resources.
When I open a blank workbook or a generic worksheet from the e-mail, I don't want to see any ribbon tabs from those workbooks at all.

I want to specifically direct the ribbons for only one workbook, like document level customization from VSTO.

In other words: I don't want that the ribbons/task panes from Office Add-ins I created displays in every workbook I open. Not only "displays", I don't want them to load at all.

Comment: Good question: at the moment its a mixture of application level for the Ribbon and workbook level for the JS (workbook is top level object, single workbook only, task pane belongs to the workbook, very limited control of the application ...) ... I see it as sort of a hybrid Cloud/Application/Workbook thing.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams do you know of any progress that has been made on this front by the office-js team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, the application level functionality is limited as it is a desktop specific scenario. App level settings, cross-workbook actions are part of our roadmap discussions. Though we don't have dates available for them. 
When you mention, a person uses "2 applications" - can you elaborate more?

Comment: Thanks. quite helpful. It is not possible to do today; however it is under discussion. Will update this thread when I have more information.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy it has been more than 2 years - how has allowing for this (quite important IMHO) scenario evolved?